# Sequelize Time with timezone Datatypes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I just want to know if there is a Sequelize data types for time with timezone. Because when I use TIME, it makes a column time without timezone on my PostgreSQL.

Comment: No, a Better way to working with timezone is store UTC time and convert it into local timezone at the time of display. Otherwise, create a different column for store timezone. It might help you.